# Montar uma tabela com registos de uma collection in PL-SQL

Tags: html, pl-sql

Viva,

Tenho uma collection com registos deste género:

TYPE TABLE_RECORD IS RECORD (n_lin number, n_col number, val varchar(4000));
TYPE TABLE_CHUNK IS TABLE OF TABLE_RECORD;

Imaginemos que tenho estes registo lá dentro:

-- 1 0 DATA
-- 1 1 UGW
-- 1 2 500

-- 2 0 DATA
-- 2 1 Teste
-- 2 2 100

O primeiro é o numero da linha, o segundo o número da coluna e o terceiro o valor.

Quero percorrer o loop de toda a collection e montar o body de uma tabela em html:

v_col_index2 := 2;

```
       htp.p( ' <tr>');
         
         FOR j IN 1..l_columns_data.COUNT LOOP
         
         if l_columns_data(j).n_col = 0 then
          htp.p('  <td> '||l_columns_data(j).val||'</td>');
          end if;
           
          
           
        for l in 1..v_col_index2  loop
          
             if l_columns_data(j).n_col = l then
          htp.p('   <td> '||l_columns_data(j).val||'</td>');
          
          end if;
          
           end loop;
         
            
        htp.p('</tr>');
       
        end loop;
```

O objetivo é que a cada 3 registos da collection que possui o numero 1 cria-se um registo na tabela "tr" e depois de acordo com a coluna criava um "td" com o valor associado.

Acham que é possivel?

Muito obrigado.